# Zooming multiple images at once javafx

Tags: java, image, javafx, zooming, tile

Language: Java FX

Objective is to have zoom functionality working(both digital and tile zoom).
By tile zoom , i mean loading next set of images corresponding to the area which is getting zoomed.

Please help::: Experience in Java FX is very limited, hence finding it very difficult to proceed

> **1.** I have one implementation for zooming which is nothing but by setting
>   the viewport for the image view.

**Lets call this digital zoom**

```
imageView.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(x, y, width, height));
```

> **2.** Another implementation for zooming is upon the zoom request , next set
>   of images will be loaded which is actually represents the zoomed area.

**Lets call this tile zoom**

```
for (int xNavigation = xWindowStart; xNavigation <= xWindowEnd; xNavigation++) {
                for (int yNavigation = yWindowStart; yNavigation <= yWindowEnd; yNavigation++) {
                    count++;
                    try {
                        image1 = new Image(new FileInputStream(
                                Constants.PATH_TILL_FOLDER + tileZoom + "/" + xNavigation + "_" + yNavigation + Constants.FILE_EXTESNION
                        ));
                        ImageView imageView1 = new ImageView();
//                        System.out.println("Zoom levels::::" + tileZoom);
                        imageView1.setX(xval);
                        imageView1.setY(yval);

                        imageView1.setFitHeight(image1.getHeight() * digitalZoomLevel);
                        imageView1.setFitWidth(image1.getWidth() * digitalZoomLevel);
                        imageView1.setPreserveRatio(true);
                        imageView1.setImage(image1);

                        root.getChildren().add(imageView1);
                        //System.out.println("X"+imageView1.getX());
                        //System.out.println("Y"+imageView1.getY());

                        yval = yval + image1.getHeight() ;

//                        System.out.println("Going to paint image :" + xNavigation + "-" + yNavigation);

                    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(DataZoom.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }

                }
                yval = 0;
                xval = xval + image1.getWidth();

            }
            System.out.println("Number of images painted tile" + count);
            System.out.println("Tile Zoom");
```

> > My Problem is first solution is developed to support 1 image only. How
> >     will i handle the digital zoom for multiple images ???.

Why zooming multiple images ?. Eg: picture of monalisa by a set of images.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I undestood your problem correctly. Why would you want to zoom into multiple pictures at once?

Anyway if you want to do that you would need to either use threads, which could cause some problems with the way you are loading the picture.

Or you could "pretend" to be multithreading by updating the picture in small steps and after each step do the same with another picture. In this case you would need one additional loop that does that job for you.

Now if you want to only zoom into one picture at a time but have multiple images inside your window the problem is pretty easy to solve. You just need to implements which image currently has focus on it.

Comment: . Eg: picture of monalisa by a set of images. And now i need to zoom it as like a single image

Comment: Alright that is quite tricky. You would need to create an algorithm that calculates a new position for each image once you zoom in and out. The calculation isn´t the real problem but optimising that process is gonna take a while

Comment: exactly man, i was wondering if there are any easy way out ;-)